# How to make background of the button fit text in 2 column layout

Tags: html, css

All these buttons have background color which fills all page width, but I want this background to cover only text and nothing else. How can I do this?

```css
[type="button"] {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Styles</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the page:
[image]

Comment: are you missing CSS code?

Comment: @ЯрославОрёл Remove the style tag contents?

Comment: sorry, i can't see the gray backgroud, where's it?

Comment: @MatteoZanini sorry, I edited my question. I was referring to all background colors of buttons

Comment: `background-clip:content-box;`should have been the idea ....

Comment: @G-Cyrillus where do I put it?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default Bootstrap Button styling by writing your own CSS. To style Button Text, wrap it in a span tag and apply CSS to it.
You can change your code like this:

```css
.custom-btn {
  background-color: white !important;
}
.custom-btn-text {
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
    [type="button"]{
     float: left;
    }
    </style>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Styles</h2>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Basic</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Default</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Primary</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Success</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Info</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Warning</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Danger</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="custom-btn"><span class="custom-btn-text">Link</span></button>      
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can I make these buttons be not as wide as they are now? I need them to occupy only the space of their text

Comment: Yes, you can! I would suggest you to get rid of bootstrap classes like `btn` `btn-link` etc because you want to style it completely yourself.

Comment: @ЯрославОрёл I've updated the code above. You can check it. I've also removed `width: 50%` from your style tag. Now, buttons will take only the as much space as the text.

Comment: I want them to be displayed as two columns and it would be cool if bootstrap button styles stayed because I want buttons to look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you ?

```css
[type="button"] {
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.btn-holder {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Styles</h2>
  <div class="btn-holder">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-holder">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-holder">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-holder">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
  </div>
</div>
```